# What does throws exception do here?

Tags: java, oracle

Reading the oracle docs on reading a URL, but I am not sure what throws exception does here?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throws exception means that if there is an Exception at any point in the code (for example, if there is a problem writing to the file you will get an IOException), then this will be passed up to the method above. However, in this case there is no method above, so if an exception is thrown your program will crash and output the text from the exception to the console.

You can also catch Exceptions if you want the program to continue:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTract();
}
```

More information about Java exceptions can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: why is it required to have the try/catch for URL's? I noticed when I removed the throws Exception, Eclipse kept telling me to add in a try/catch everywhere. I thought try/catch was just for your own convience to have so you can find an error quickly?

Comment: The try/catch is required for URL's because the constructor for URL was defined to throw a MalformedURLException if it's not valid. [See here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)). 


Exception handling and try/catch is used in all sorts of situations where a method in a program cannot do what it's expected to do, for example if you enter the URL "http://.com" it would not be able to load that so an exception would be thrown, which you can then either throw again, or handle in a try/catch block

Answer (score 1):

Some of the methods called inside that program (for instance IO-related things usually do) throw [checked exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions). Checked exceptions must either be handled with a `try/catch` or included in the method signature with a `throws` clause, which those IO-related methods have.

By marking the main method with `throws Exception` they're essentially saying "If an exception occurs in my program, just let it die. I don't want to handle them.". In real-world code you might want to handle things such as the Internet connection being down more gracefully than just letting the entire program die, but in this case they just wanted to write a short example.